# What is AuthServiceProvider in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I have got a file called

```
AuthServiceProvider.php
```

in the *Providers directory* in *Laravel* project.

I actually don't understand about how it works and why it's needed

Can anyone explain with details?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can learn about it in the docs here https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/authentication

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AuthServiceProvider is the default guard that Laravel uses to give the service authentication in the system. But if you need you can make your own guards for specific situations, in that case you will have you own AuthServiceProvider.
For eg. In one system that we made, the customer had his own database with it's specific users table, we can't use the default Laraver AuthServiceProvider. Because the table have other fields. So we created our CustomAuthProvider. It's complex, but you need to declare the driver en config/auth.php

```
...
'defaults' => [
    'guard' => 'web',
    'passwords' => 'users',
    'provider' => 'custom' // Our custom driver
],
...
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'custom', // Our custom driver
    ],
    ...
],
...
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => Modules\Pickandroll\Entities\User::class,
    ],
    'custom' => [
        'driver' => 'pickandrolluser', //Our Custom Auth Provider
        'model' => Modules\Pickandroll\Entities\User::class,
    ]
],
```

and the custom module provider we register our custom auth provider

```
 public function register()
    {
        Auth::provider('pickandrolluser', function ($app, array $config) {
            return new PickandrollUserProvider($config['model']);
        });
    }
```

and the class PickandrollUserProvider that extends use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\UserProvider;

I know it's complex but maybe it helps to understand this topic